# React.js Route - previous page stays after redirection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

js and am using `react-router-dom`.

**Say I have 2 files -** 1. **`dashboard.js`** file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import WYSIWYG from './editor/wysiwyg';

export default class Dashboard extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/wysiwyg" component={WYSIWYG}/>
                </Switch>
                <ul id="DASHBOARD-MENU">
                    <li><Link to={{ pathname: '/wysiwyg'}}>WYSIWYG</Link></li>
                </ul>     
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

> Note the `ul` with `id="DASHBOARD-MENU"` above

---

2nd - **`wysiwyg.js`** file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Wysiwyg extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="WYSIWYG-CONTAINER">  
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

> Note the `div` with `id="WYSIWYG-CONTAINER"` in the above snippet

---

### My problem is:

After redirection to `WYSIWYG` container from my `dashboard`, I can still see the  - `<ul id="DASHBOARD-MENU" ..` rendered **below** the `<div id="WYSIWYG-CONTAINER ..`.

**What I understood -** is the component `WYSIWYG` is rendered replacing `<Route` declared in my `dashboard.js` file.

### What I want:

I don't want the `"DASHBOARD-MENU"` element to render in my `"WYSIWYG"` page.

Is it possible?

Comment: That's how RR works. If you don't want dashboard menu to be shown, you have to put it into another route inside the `Switch`. Getting ? Your _what I understood_ part is correct.. the `component` prop replaces the `<Route>` if it matches. The others stay the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired behavior can be obtained by considering both as different routes, and hence rendering only one of them depending on the path:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import WYSIWYG from './editor/wysiwyg';

const Dashboard = () => (
  <ul id="DASHBOARD-MENU">
    <li><Link to={{ pathname: '/wysiwyg'}}>WYSIWYG</Link></li>
  </ul>
);

export default class Dashboard extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route exact path="/wysiwyg" component={WYSIWYG}/>
                </Switch>     
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```